# Most convenient way to manage files on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file-io, avfoundation

I have an iPhone app that allows users to create content (mainly things that are stored as binary data) while recording video. So the output of the app are multiple files, the recording and the user generated content. Because between the two there is a relationship, I though of archiving them and present them to the user as a single file, a bundle. But since the video can be huge, archiving is becoming less of an option because of the time needed to archive/unarchive the file. What other options do I have? When I record I write buffers to disk, so I'm not loading the file in memory. Would be nice to be able to write into an archive, but I'm almost sure it's not possible.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you understand the current [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/).  (Perversely, you need an Apple developer ID to see that web page.)  Failure to follow the guidelines can cause your app to be rejected or to fail mysteriously in the field.

Comment: You could create folders in Documents, one for each set, and make them available to the user via [iTunes File Sharing](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app)